# ASPNET Map a property of an object into new array

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a service which returns a custom object like this:

```
public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
```

The image class is like the following:

```
public string Url { get; set; }
public string MobilelOverride { get; set; }
public string AltText { get; set; }
public string Attribution { get; set; }
public int? Width { get; set; }
public int? Height { get; set; }
```

In our view model, I have an array of strings.

```
public List<String> ProductImageUrls { get; set; }
```

I am not sure how to convert the List of images into a list of the `Image.Url` for the `ProductImageUrls` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to `SELECT` the `Url` property of each `Image`, and place it into a `List` of `String` (because Url is a `String`).

It is pretty easy using **Linq** :

```
ProductImageUrls  = Images.Select(a => a.Url).ToList();
```